# Вытащить из обьекта css и присвоить его элементу

Tags: javascript, css, массивы, объекты

Я хочу вытащить из обьекта ключи и присвоить его элементу но между свойствами есть не нужная мне запятая, как исправить её на двоиточие и пробел

код:

```js
let styles = {
  "background-color": "#111",
  "color": "red",
}

let stylesArr = Object.entries(styles);

stylesArr.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let test = stylesArr.join(';');
  console.log(test);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как-то так

```
let result = Object.entries(styles).map(([key, value]) =>key + "= " + value).join(";");
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!

Comment: Да не вопрос всегда пожалуйста